# is there a way to sort variable length number strings easily in sort or other unix-like / gnutools?

Tags: sorting, unix

Is there a way to make unix' `sort` command operate on numbers that are not the same number of digits?  If I do `sort -n` I get the following output for my sample data,

```
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[0]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[10]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[11]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[1]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[2]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[3]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[4]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[5]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[6]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[7]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[8]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[9]/dropped_packets
```

but what I actually want is:

```
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[0]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[1]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[2]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[3]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[4]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[5]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[6]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[7]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[8]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[9]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[10]/dropped_packets
pdvoq_shared_mma:voq_counters[11]/dropped_packets
```

I could certainly figure out how to parse this in python or something and then sort on the extracted fields, but it always seems like unix has these sorts of things solved already  :)

Comment: This question belongs on [unix.se], as it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data in file data.txt:

```
sort -V data.txt
```

will produce the output you want.
You need GNU sort for this.